# Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException:

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Data Mongo and using @DBRef in my model class and when I execute the query I get the below error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dbrefDemoApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{'addresses.$city' : "_param_0"'}
                               ^
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DbrefDemoApplication.main(DbrefDemoApplication.java:22) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{'addresses.$city' : "_param_0"'}
                               ^
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{'addresses.$city' : "_param_0"'}
                               ^
```

Address.java

```
@Document(collection = "address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    private long addressId;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private long zipcode;

    public Address() {
        System.out.println("CAlling default cons");
    }

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public Address(long addressId, String address, String city, String state, long zipcode) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
        this.address = address;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public long getZipcode() {
        return zipcode;
    }

    public void setZipcode(long zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Address [address=" + address + ", city=" + city + ", state=" + state + ", zipcode=" + zipcode + "]";
    }
}
```

Person.java

```
public class Person {
    @Id
    private Long personId;

    private String name;

    private int age;

    @DBRef(db = "address")
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

    public Person() {
    }

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public Person(Long personId, String name, int age) {
        super();
        this.personId = personId;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Long getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(Long personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public List<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [personId=" + personId + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", addresses=" + addresses + "]";
    }
}
```

**Repo class**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>{
    @Query("{'name' : ?0}")
    public Iterable<Person> searchByName(String personName);

    @Query(value = "{'addresses.$city' : ?0'}")
    Person findByAddresses_City(String city);
}
```

Result

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(1),
    "name" : "Achilles",
    "age" : 0,
    "addresses" : [],
    "_class" : "com.example.demo.model.Person"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(2),
    "name" : "Hektor",
    "age" : 0,
    "addresses" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "address",
            "$id" : NumberLong(1),
            "$db" : "address"
        }
    ],
    "_class" : "com.example.demo.model.Person"
}
```

Below both the queries breaks !

```
Person p = personRepository.findByAddresses_City("221b Baker Street");
System.out.println(p);
```

and

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("addresses.$id").is(new ObjectId("2")));
List<Person> l = mongoTemplate.find(query, Person.class);
System.out.println(l);
```

EDIT-1:
I corrected : `Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("addresses.$id").is(1L));`

But this still doesn't brings anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quote near `?0`, in your code you have written `?0'`:

```
@Query(value = "{'addresses.$city' : ?0'}")
```

should be

```
@Query(value = "{'addresses.$city' : ?0}")
```